# What is the task of this oracle operator

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_DIM_PrcProjectSppmse AS
SELECT
    'PROJECT' as Parent,
    'PRJCATE_' || ListItemId as Child,
    ...
        FROM
    MyVIEW
```

What does the this operator '||' above mean and how is it named?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` is string concatenation. In C# it would be `+` in VB `&`.

```
'aaa' || 'bbb' ==> 'aaabbb'
```

Comment: How would you use TO_NCHAR() method with the 'PROJECT' and the 'PRJCATE_' || ListItemId as Child, line of code? I cant make it working always getting: character set mismatch Ora 12704

Comment: Note that a unicode string literal is written as `N'abc'`. If `ListItemId` is a NVARCHAR2 then use `N'PRJCATE_' || ListItemId as Child`. If `ListItemId` is a number use `'PRJCATE_' || TO_CHAR(ListItemId) as Child`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a concatenation operator - it appends the second value to the first.
It's called a Concatenation operator.

In other languages you may see this as the plus symbol `+` or an ampersand `&`

In your example the value of `ListItemId` is appended to the string 'PRJCATE_'. e.g.
if `ListItemId` had the value 15 you'd get  'PRJCATE_15' as the second column.